# WebApi 2 + OData v4 complete example

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I can't seem to find a **complete** working example of webapi2 + odata v4. Nothing works.
Do you have a complete, working and standalone example to provide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are kinds of samples in github, refer to https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4 which is based on Web Api odata library.

Also there is a library called restier which only requires several line of code to make a DB exposed via EF as OData service, refer to https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/RESTier for end to end examples.